# How can i setup Bootstrap, Angular.js and mySQL together

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-bootstrap

Im very new to this World of Angular and Html. Im using brackets, i did a small project which was setup by my friend and he is not available to help anymore. Im trying to find detailed process so i can start writing HTML using Bootstrap with Angular framework which will use mySQL database. Project im trying to create is full stack so i will be creating front and back end APIs. Im confident with creating APIs once everything is setup but surprisingly im stuck at such a basic thing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For scaffolding angular apps, there is a npm module called Yeoman, which can get you pretty far as a start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very broad and can generate lots of discussion. So, I am trying to give you some guidelines you can use in your journey.

1. **AngularJS with Bootstrap**: if you are using AngularJs 1.x then I recomend going with UI Bootstrap. Check it out: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
2. **Create a web service to provide data**: Normally, we need a service (running in a web server) to manage data exchange. You can develop it using several programing languages with a web server such as: Javascript with NodeJS, PHP with Apache, Java with Tomcat or .Net with IIS. Next, you can exchange data between AngularJS and your web service through Ajax.
3. **Connect your web service to your database**: Finally, your web service is capable to connect to a database (e.g.: MySQL) and send it back to your front-end (in this case your AngularJS page). The web server is also the best place to put business rules (e.g.: permissions, security control, business constraints, etc)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow and the world of web development. This is definitely not a bad question but is far too broad to be answered in any meaningful way here. MySQL, Angular, and Bootstrap really have nothing to do with each other so there's many ways to go about this.

To start, I'd recommend exploring an existing web framework and building a sample application. There are tons of web frame works out there with tutorials all over the web. One I'd recommend for beginners is Michael Haartl's Rails tutorial which uses Bootstrap.

Comment: Unfortunately i have no time to explore. There is something urgent that needs to be setup. In a nutshell i just want to know how can i use bootstrap and Angular together? initial setup before i can start writing the HTML. I researched for mySQL and i think it will be an easy download an install. Thanks Anthony

Comment: I'd consider looking at some of the projects in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Projects-using-AngularJS under the "Examples" section. Also check out https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/.